# SwiftUI Image/SDWebImage Size

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm messing with a dumb situation. I'm struggling making some images the same height and width for all but its seems to be hard. Code and screen below:

```
HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 16) {
     WebImage(url: URL(string: "\(news.imageURL)"))
         .resizable()
         .scaledToFill()
         .frame(width: 120, height: 80)
         .cornerRadius(8)
                
         VStack (alignment: .leading) {
             Text(news.title ?? "")
                 .font(.system(size: 15))
                 .fontWeight(.semibold)
                 .lineLimit(3)
                 .foregroundStyle(.black)
                    
             Spacer()
                    
             Text(news.sourceStr ?? "")
                 .font(.system(size: 10))
                 .foregroundColor(.gray)
        }
}
```

Screen:

[image]

Some help :) I know its dumb but i'm kinda noob

Comment: You likely need aspect ratio and/or clipped shape

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. For image, you need to adjust the aspect ratio to fill the area and fix the frame.
2. Fix the alignment on rows by putting in a `Spacer` after the `VStack` containing Text
3. Optionally add padding around it

```swift
HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 16) {
     
     WebImage(url: URL(string: "\(news.imageURL)"))
         .resizable()
         // [1]
         .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
         .frame(width: 120, height: 80)
         .clipped()
         .cornerRadius(8)
                
         VStack (alignment: .leading) {
             Text(news.title ?? "")
                 .font(.system(size: 15))
                 .fontWeight(.semibold)
                 .lineLimit(3)
                 .foregroundStyle(.black)
                    
             Spacer()
                    
             Text(news.sourceStr ?? "")
                 .font(.system(size: 10))
                 .foregroundColor(.gray)
        }

        // [2] 
        Spacer()

}
// [3]
.padding()
```